# Error not Triggering in Custom Model Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple validation in one of my Rails models, but it doesn't seem to be triggering an error like I want.

```
before_save :check_future_date

 private  
   def check_future_date
     puts "=============================================================="
     puts self.article.date
     puts Date.today
     if self.article.date <= Date.today
       puts "error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"           
       errors[:base] << "Sorry, you must post at least a day in advance"
     end
   end
```

I know that the logic is being triggered because in the console, I see:

```
 ==============================================================
 2013-04-06
 2013-04-29
 error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

However, the record is still saved, and no error message is shown.  I have also tried:

```
errors.add(:base, 'Sorry, you must post at least a day in advance')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the custom validation method, instead of performing a `before_save`.

Change

```
before_save :check_future_date
```

To

```
validate :check_future_date
```